# bash: Problems with glob negation and multiple patterns

Tags: bash, glob

I am trying to write a glob pattern that returns a list of files that do not end in one of 2 possible suffixes: done and monthly

The list of files in my test directory is:

```
foo.done
foo.montly
foo.pdf
foo.txt
```

I am perfectly successful if I perform negation for only 1 suffix:

```
ls  !(*done) or ls  !(*monthly)
```

However, when I tried something like this:

```
ls  !({*monthly,*done})
```

I get this:

```
foo.done
foo.monthly
foo.pdf
foo.pdf
foo.txt
foo.txt
```

Can someone help me understand a result that not only doesn't produce what I want in terms of negation but also lists duplicates!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `|` to separate the patterns in the pattern list ([docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)):

> If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin,
>   several extended pattern matching operators are recognized. In the
>   following description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more
>   patterns separated by a ‘|’.

Result:

```
$ shopt -s extglob

$ ls
foo.done  foo.monthly  foo.pdf  foo.txt

$ ls *.!(monthly|done)
foo.pdf  foo.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Cody. This syntax does work although I am surprised that the {} syntax which works well in the non negation case breaks down under negation. It appears that my understanding of {} syntax is not correct!

Comment: @MadMax Yeah.. as far as I know, there is no way to negate brace expansion.